# PHP MySQL запрос SELECT SUM() GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Помогите составить запрос в PHP коде. Нужно подсчитать баланс по id в таблице. Записей может быть больше 1.
Запрос:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

берёт только первый попавшийся id, а остальные пропускает. Как сделать, чтобы считало по всем id сумму?
Пример(записи):
1) `id = 1, amount = 34`
2) `id = 1, amount = 12`
3) `id = 3, amount = 12`

Должно быть результатом SUM(amount)(2 записи с id 1) = 46, но ответ будет 34, а вторую запись с тем же id не учитывает, а нужно чтобы учитывало.

Comment: Что такое "сумма по всем id" ? это отдельные суммы по каждому (тогда просто уберите limit) или вообще общая сумма по таблице одной цифрой (тогда уберите group by, order by и limit)

Comment: Запрос считает сумму amount для каждого id, и возвращает максимальную из них (а не "первый попавшийся id").

Comment: Записи, где amount с одинаковыми ID не все подсчитывает. А так запрос получает наибольшую сумму по таблице по id и выводит одну наибольшую.

Comment: Покажите лучше пример исходных данных (4-5 записей) и желаемый результат для именно таких данных.

Comment: Да что вообще непонятно не понимаю? Запрос считает SUM(amount) только по первой попавшееся записи c ID, остальные отбрасывает из-за GROUP BY, а мне нужно чтобы считало по группах ID сразу.

Comment: *Должно быть результатом SUM(amount)(2 записи с id 1) = 46, но ответ будет 34, а вторую запись с тем же id не учитывает, а нужно чтобы учитывало.* Что-то Вы, друг мой, какую-то ахинею несёте. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c98aa6b3bec840e523d119917656631d)

Comment: Я уже разжевал даже, что должно быть на выходе. Из-за GROUP BY берёт только первую запись с записей по одному и тому же ID, а нужно, чтобы считало по всем записям с одинаковых id в том числе. ID может быть разное. В примере указал единицу.